# I can't display images in razor pages

Tags: c#, html, blazor, razor-pages

So i am trying to add an image to my button, i have added my image in the wwwrooot folder. But when using the code :

```
<img src="~/calculette.png"/>
```

The image doesnt show, it just does this : (https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGP1r.png)

So i have tried to use the default image in wwwroot which is named "icon-192.png" and it does the same thing, as if doesn't find the image.

What can i do ?

Comment: Remove ~ sign and retry.

Comment: Please add more details to your question. Share the Program.cs and the Startup.cs for your project. Share also the content of your view. Moreover, open the browser developer tools, go the Network tab and check the response status code for the image request. Share all of these details in your question.

Comment: The most important one is probably the information you can get for the image request from the Network tab of your browser's developer tools.

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all HTML tags.

Comment: Okay ,

So i tried to just remove the "~" and it worked !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay ,

So i tried to just remove the "~" and it worked !

Comment: you must provide as a comment

Comment: Instead of answering your own question for this kind of miss, you just add a comment to your question. One of the moderator will then `close` your question